# Values missing or misaligned when entering multiple rows from form - PHP/MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to submit multiple rows from a form into MySQL database using PHP (having used [Insert multiple rows to database from HTML form using MySQLi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064039/insert-multiple-rows-to-database-from-html-form-using-mysqli) and multiple other articles as reference).

The problem I am encountering is that the first row submits fine but subsequent rows submit some values I did not expect.

I have tried multiple ways of looping through the rows (see commented lines) to address this but not found a solution yet.

```
// $number = count($_POST["ps_id"]);
  // echo $number;
  $ps_id     = $_POST["ps_id"];
  $ds_id = $_POST["ds_id"];
  $hole_id = $_POST["hole_id"];
  $strokes = $_POST["strokes"];
  $hole_strokes  = $_POST["hole_strokes"];
  $par = $_POST["hole_par"];
  $pkey = $_POST["pkey"];
  $c_id  = $_POST["c_id"];
  $this_hole = $_POST["holeno"];

  $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO strokes (players_id, days_id, hole_id, strokes, points, net_strokes, par, pkey, course_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

  // for ($i=0; $i<count($ds_id); $i++) {
  // for ($i=0; $i<$number; $i++) {
  foreach ($_POST['ps_id'] as $i => $ps_id){
      $ds_id = $ds_id[$i];
      $hole_id = $hole_id[$i];
      $strokes = $strokes[$i];
      $hole_strokes = $hole_strokes[$i];
      $par = $par[$i];
      $pkey = $pkey[$i];
      $c_id = $c_id[$i];
      // $ps_id = $ps_id[$i];
      $net_strokes += ((int)$strokes-(int)$hole_strokes);
      $pts += ((int)$par-(int)$net_strokes)+2;
      if ($pts < 0) {
        $points = 0;
      } else {
        $points = $pts;
      }

      $stmt->bind_param('iiiiiiiii', $ps_id, $ds_id, $hole_id, $strokes, $points, $net_strokes, $par, $pkey, $c_id);
      // echo "ds_id: ".$ds_id." and hole_id: ".$hole_id." and strokes: ".$strokes." and points: ".$points." and net_strokes: ".$net_strokes." and pts: ".$pts." and pkey: ".$pkey." and par: ".$par." and c_id: ".$c_id." and ps_id: ".$ps_id."<br><br><br>";

      $stmt->execute();

      // setcookie('g_holeno', $nexthole, 3600, '/');
      // header("Location: ../open/index.php?s=1");

  }
      // echo "Success";
      $nexthole += (int)$this_hole[0]+1;
      // echo "Next hole: ".$nexthole;
  $stmt->close();
```

Values for subsequent rows are properly formatted when submitted from the form:

```
ps_id[]: 1
strokes[]: 4
ds_id[]: 7
pkey[]: 5
holeno[]: 1
hole_id[]: 19
hole_par[]: 4
c_id[]: 4
hole_strokes[]: 1
ps_id[]: 2
strokes[]: 4
ds_id[]: 7
pkey[]: 5
holeno[]: 1
hole_id[]: 19
hole_par[]: 4
c_id[]: 4
hole_strokes[]: 1
ps_id[]: 3
strokes[]: 4
...
```

...but for rows 2 onwards only ps_id (players_id) and net_strokes submits correctly to db:

```
id, days_id, hole_id, strokes, points, net_strokes, par, pkey, course_id, players_id
'103','7','19','4','3','3','4','5','4','1'
'104','0','9','0','2','3','0','0','0','2'
'105','0','0','0','1','3','0','0','0','3'
'106','0','0','0','0','3','0','0','0','4'
```

I suspect the error is somehow associated with the calculated variables but have not been able to find a solution on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **overwrite** your data every iteration:

```
$ds_id = $ds_id[$i];     // array `$ds_id` becomes SINGLE value
$hole_id = $hole_id[$i]; // same here and so on
// etc
```